# OSX Mail reply with highlighted text as quote

Tags: mail.app

In Mail app 7.0 on OSX 10.9, If I highlight a piece of text and then choose `Message` → `Forward` it creates a new email with the relevant text as a quote. How do I replicate this behaviour with `Message` → `Reply`?

I believe this functionality was present in an earlier version of Mail.

**Edit:** unchecking `Preferences` → `Composing` → `Quote the text of the original message` causes this behaviour. With it checked (the default setting), any highlighted text becomes the quote. However with no highlighted text the entire message I am replying to is quoted, behaviour I don't want so this is frustrating.

Comment: This still seems to work for me?

Comment: Ah thx, I've now seen that an option affects behaviour, edited the Q with more info

Comment: I'll leave this open but I doubt this is easily fixable.

Comment: Probably can't be natively fixed, no. Only option I can think of would be using an AppleScript and the extension Mail Act-On. At least selecting some whitespace before hitting reply should make the following quote-deletion easier ;-)

Comment: Ha, cool suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was googling for the same problem and bumped into here. For people who don't know how to mark a piece of text as a quote in OSX Mail 10.1 I accidently found the way to do it.

You should:

1. Highlight the text you want to mark as a quote
2. Hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>

The whole line will be converted into a quote.

[image: Quoting in Mail App 10.1]